# How I can decode and access Double from JSON using Alamofire and Swift Decode

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, decode

I try do decode and access specific exchange rate for specific currency using Alamofire and Swift decode:

this is my model:

```
    struct Listek: Codable {
    let base: String
    let date: String
    let rates: [String: Double]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case base = "base"
        case date = "date"
        case rates = "rates"
    }
}
```

this is Alamofire API call + decode

```
let apiToContact = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest"
    AF.request(apiToContact).responseJSON { (response) in
    print(response)
    guard let data = response.data else { return }
    do {
    let st = try JSONDecoder().decode(Listek.self, from: data)
        print (st.rates)
        print (st.base)
        print (st.date)

    }
    catch {
    print("error")
    }
```

So far so good, but I fail in accessing the single currency and its rate value. I would like declare a variable "JPYrate" with value of JPY rate from JSON. Can you please navigate me?

Comment: did you try st.rates["JPY"]?

Comment: I think you need to explain further what your problem is so we can help you correctly. "fail in accessing" is very vague.

Comment: Aside: don't print `"error"` (the string). `print(error)` instead to see what really went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the value corresponding to key `JPY` from `rates` `Dictionary` like so,

```
let JPYrate = st.rates["JPY"]
```

Also, there is no need to create `enum CodingKeys`, if the key names are same as the property names. So, your `struct Listek` looks like,

```
struct Listek: Codable {
    let base: String
    let date: String
    let rates: [String:Double]
}
```

Comment: thank you, completely correct and you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

`exchangeratesapi` seems to send consistent data. if so my suggestion is to decode the rates into a dedicated struct

```
struct Listek: Decodable {
    let base: String
    let date: String
    let rates: Rates
}

struct Rates: Decodable {
    let CAD, HKD, ISK, PHP, DKK, HUF, CZK, AUD, RON, SEK, IDR, INR, BRL, RUB, HRK, JPY, THB, CHF, SGD, PLN, BGN, TRY, CNY, NOK, NZD, ZAR, USD, MXN, ILS, GBP, KRW, MYR : Double
}
```

Then you can get the rate directly

```
print(st.rates.JPY)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can make a computed property to access the JPY rate:

```swift
var jpyRate: Double? { rates["JPY"] }
```

Or parse the rates into a specific type as recommended by @vadian.

Second, you can use Alamofire's `responseDecodable` method to do the decoding automatically.

```swift
AF.request(apiToContact).responseDecodable(of: Listek.self) { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```